# openVPN http-proxy-option version (EXT1)?

Tags: proxy, openvpn

I have a question about http-proxy-option in openVPN. I have a client *.ovpn file which works on Windows, but doesn't work on Mac OS X or Linux. Here is my client config file (key and certificate are inside)

```
auth-user-pass  pass.txt
client
dev tap
proto tcp
remote 177.889.918.123 8080
redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp
route-method exe
keepalive 5 30
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 2

http-proxy-option AGENT 'Mozilla/7.0+ (compatible; MSIE 4.01; Windows NT 5.0)'
http-proxy-option EXT1 'X-Online-Host: pas.testu.com'
http-proxy-option EXT1 'Host: pas.testu.com'
http-proxy 191.103.196.127 8000
http-proxy-retry
http-proxy-timeout 360
```

openVPN is compiled with lzo and --enable-password-save.

I got this error:

```
"Bad http-proxy-option or missing parameter: 'EXT1' "
```

does EXT1 is a version type?

I've also tried to set my user agent string to "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Safari/534.50"
but that failed, too.

Can someone help me please?
I've searching the manual, geek forum, even reading the recommended openVPN book, and still I don't understand the problem.

*[of course the IP and the host in the above example are not actual/valid]*

Answer (score 1):

`http-proxy-option EXT1` is a non-standard extension to open VPN. Your first try should be commenting-out these two options.
If your scenary really needs X-Online-Host: and/or Host: you only option is to look for patches that implement `http-proxy-option EXT1` in openvpn.

Answer (score -1):

User NMD VPN instead of OpenVPN. Your setting will work fine after that.